# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-sensors, sensormanager

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8:
illegal start byte 0x88 string: '!3o�y�' in call to NewStringUTF from int
android.hardware.SystemSensorManager.nativeGetNextSensor(android.hardware.Sensor, int)
```

Happens in line:

```
sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Tablet, Android Lollipop.
I've never faced exceptions like this before. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Can you please post some more code !

Comment: hi, @AbhinavArora, there is no real need in more code. This is very specific problem in JNI, the problem is that String Context.SENSOR_SERVICE gets encoded incorrectly in the JNI lib...

Comment: Are you sure that is the line that is causing the problem? The error seems to be indicating `illegal start byte 0x88 string`. What is this string it is having problems with? Where is it coming from? I agree with @AbhinavArora that it could be helpful if we saw more code.

Comment: the String is Context.SENSOR_SERVICE constant which is "sensor". Crashes Nexus 9 Tablet and only it as I can see.